# Implementation of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java

I have an application that sends a request from different server depending on the configuration/profile of the user..

For example, `User A` will access our website and process a transaction.. Our backend will call a 3rd party server based on his profile (ex: https://serviceA.com) to gather the data..  `User B` might also have the same 3rd party server.. But other might have different URL.

Do I need to implement Connection Pooling like `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` to improve performance?

Comment: Get it to work first, Always optimize after. If not you add complexity and t still might not perform, since you cannot determine bottlenecks until after you benchmark.

Comment: on topic https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to implement Connection Pooling like PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager to improve performance?

Depends on the kind of load you expect your system to be under.
If you can do without this manager, I'd avoid using it.

This is because in order to use it you'll need to correctly configure it and configuration errors might not show up during testing.

Take this aspect for example ([more info](http://www.javabyexamples.com/connection-pooling-using-apache-httpclient-4))

> By default, the maximum number of connections is 20 and the maximum connection number per route is 2. However, these values are generally too low for real-world applications. For example, when all the connections are busy with handling other requests, HttpClient won't create a new connection if the number exceeds 20. As a result, any class that tries to execute a request won't get a connection. Instead, it'll eventually get a ConnectionPoolTimeoutException exception.

Therefore, using this thing for your project increases the complexity (via extra configuration) and raises the risks of something backfiring if it is misconfigured.

On the upside, it can speed up some stuff if you have some routes with a high load.

**In summary:** Use it if absolutely necessary. Otherwise, not.
Based on the [description](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management) of this class here, it looks kind of complicated to configure with many aspects and nuances.

Comment: Do I need to share pool on all the request? regardless of what is the route?

Comment: Just don't configure anything and use the standard `HttpClient` class without any modifications. If you run into performance bottlenecks, then you optimise.